# How to keep the previous state after navigation

Tags: react-native, state

```
//Home page

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {time: ""}
    }

    render(){
      const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
      return(
        <View>
          <TextInput onChangeText={(time) => this.setState({ time })} placeholder = "enter time" />
          <TouchableOpacity style={{marginTop: 10, height: 20, width: 50, borderRadius: 6, borderColor: 'white', backgroundColor:'red'}}
            onPress = { () => {
                navigate('Wait', {
                  time: this.state.time * 1000
                })
            }}
            >
            <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>add</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )
    }
}


//Waitlist page

class Wait extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: []}
  }

  renderTime(){
    return this.state.data.map((item) => {
      return(
        <View>
          <TimerCountdown
           initialSecondsRemaining={ item }
           allowFontScaling={true}
           style={{ fontSize: 20 }}
          />
        </View>
      )
    })
  }

  updatestate(time){
    var temp = this.state.data
    temp.push(time)
    this.setState({data: temp})
  }

  render(){
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const time = navigation.getParam('time', 'NO-Name');

    return(
      <View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress = {()=>{ this.updatestate(time)}}>
              <Text> Update </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View>
            {this.renderTime()}
          </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I am trying to write a function to keep adding countdown timer to another page. After the user enter the input time, it should navigate to the waitlist page and update the state and render all the timers. The above code does not work because each time I navigate to that page the state will reset.

I also tried it with the AsyncStorage. I was able to add the time to the AsyncStorage on the home page and render each time on the waitlist page. But the problem is all the timers will reset every time I add a new timer.

I just want to know how can I keep the previous state after navigate to another page. Can someone please show me some examples? Thanks a lot.

Documentation for timer-countdown: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-timer-countdown